# Import function from a dynamic js.file name

Tags: node.js, dynamic, import

I am trying to import from a file with a name passed from console. This works for the first import from JSON, but when I try to import a js file, I can't use the function:

```
let vis = process.argv[2];
  import(`./${vis}.json`).then((vis2) => {
    import(`./${vis}.js`).then((mani)=>{
      console.log(mani);
      await mani().then()...
    })
  })
```

vis2 is imported correctly.
mani return a function correctly (there is only one function in that file):

```
mani: [AsyncFunction: mani]
```

But when I try to call on the function in the code in the next line, I get an error message:

> TypeError: mani is not a function

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the function from the js file? Since the js file name is dynamic (passed through console), I can't use the regular import {} from ''; structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not specify a module name that is constructed dynamically with the standard `import` syntax because of the static nature of the ESM module system - the dependency graph is actually built ahead of actual code execution, at which point the module names should be known.

But you can do this with the dynamic `import()` syntax - which consists in a function that returns a promise that resolves to the `module` object.

```
import(dynamicName)
  .then(function(module){
    // Use module here.
  })
```

I am not sure that you would be able to straight-up import a `.json` file that way though - unless your build system or execution environment is set up to handle some appropriate kinds of code transform. This is because a `.json` file doesn't qualify as an ESM module.

Comment: Thanks! This allowed me to import a json, but not a js file? I try to import a function from a js file and the console.log shows it imported ok ([AsyncFunction: functionX]), but when I try to call on the function, I get an error message "TypeError: functionX is not a function";

Comment: Any js file that qualifies as an ESM module should work fine. - and as you point out, It actually looks it is imported just fine here. Could you maybe specify in your post how the js file you're trying to import exports its api?

Comment: Just saw your edit, the promise returned by `import()` resolves to a module object - not to the export itself. It looks like your js file has a `mani` named export, so you should try something like this: `import(`./${vis}.js`).then(async function(module) { await module.mani() })`